# Can topic models be used on a small text?

Tags: nlp, topic-modeling

I have a single document which includes totally 438 sentences (so it is not very big). But, I am wondering if I can use a topic modeling system to tell me which sentences are more related. Is it possible?

As I have seen in all papers and topics about topic modeling, these systems usually work based on very large corpora. I would like to know how accurate the systems will be on such a small dataset.

Meanwhile, my main aim is not to do topic modeling for the text, but I want to use it just as a feature (whether the two sentences belong to the same topic ro not) to do another task.

I would also like to know how the topics are determined? Is there any pre-defined set of topics in each topic modelling tool? Or they are user-defined topics?

Best Regard,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Treat every sentence as a document in a standard topic modelling technique such as Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA).

The topics are not determined a priori. In LDA, a topic is essentially a distribution over terms. You just need to pre-specify the number of topics. Words co-occurring frequently would tend to belong to the same topic.

To answer your second question: "Meanwhile, my main aim is not to do topic modeling for the text, but I want to use it just as a feature (whether the two sentences belong to the same topic ro not) to do another task."...

After computing the theta matrix (NxK) (N:=#docs, K:=#topics), you can compute metrics such as KL-divergence etc. on these N distributions (one for each document) to know which documents are topically related to one another.

Comment: Wow! Really? Can I use them? That was very good news :) Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks so much Debasis for your post, I would just like to clarify if I got this right. So, by calculating the KL divergence between two documents (distribution over a set topics) assuming two documents relate to different topics, the score would represent the statistical difference between the two distributions ("difference between the kinds of topics they represent")? If so, is it right to say that this score represents how different the post are from each other since they relate to different topics?

Comment: yes @Cosq u got it right... each document is a row vector of the theta matrix... calculating some notion of similarity (e.g. inner product) or some distance measure (e.g. Euclidean distance) would provide an estimate on how similar or how different two documents are... yes, if ur documents are posts they would likely indicate the posts are on similar or different topics.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much @Debasis.  Just to update, so far I have retrieved the document row vectors and have calculated the similarity measures between them (KL divergence, inner product and other similarity measures) I would say this is works well !

Comment: @Cosq just a reminder that KL divergence is a distance measure, whereas inner product is a similarity one...